# Current setting in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-sct

I'm converting oracle to postgresql using AWS SCT tool.

I found the following line in one of function:

```
select (CLOCK_TIMESTAMP() AT TIME ZONE COALESCE(CURRENT_SETTING('aws_oracle_ext.tz', TRUE), 'UTC'))::TIMESTAMP(0)
```

Is there any other alternative of this setting `aws_oracle_ext.tz` in postgresql? I just want to remove dependency of all the extension of aws `aws_oracle_ext`.

Can I use the following one?

`select (CLOCK_TIMESTAMP() AT TIME ZONE COALESCE(CURRENT_SETTING(now()::text, TRUE), 'UTC'))::TIMESTAMP(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks silly (besides, it is not Oracle code).

- If you want the wall clock time in your session time zone, use

  ```
  SELECT clock_timestamp()::timestamp
  ```
- If you want the transaction timestamp, use

  ```
  SELECT localtimestamp
  ```